# Output one value into an array from an array of Objects containing value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Ive been trying combinations but can't figure this out. I am trying to pull out an array containing just the values from a value pair within an array containing objects.

INPUT

```
const myUsers = [
    { id: '1', name: 'bob' },
    { id: '56', name: 'bert' },
    { id: '32', name: 'Jenny' }
]
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
[1,56,32]
```

CURRENT CODE

```
const idRecordsOnly = myUsers.map(item => {
    const container = {};
    container[item.id] = container[item.id]
    return container;
})

console.log(idRecordsOnly)
```

Comment: `const idRecordsOnly = myUsers.map(item =>item.id)` , just return id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Aurabliss! the answer is below

```
const idRecordsOnly = myUsers.map(item =>item.id)
```

Comment: You can also utilize [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) there too. For instance: `const idRecordsOnly = myUsers.map(({ id }) => id);`